# why is it necessary to disable web security to a chrome browser to enable the connection between Tableau and Data Hug data Source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, security, tableau-api

I am using a Data Hug Connector java script to enable the connection between Tableau and Data Hug data Source.

First i have to disable the web security, other my Java script will not run.
I have to run chrome like this  as mentioned below:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

is there any alternate to it , that without disabling web security i can use my java script?

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site. This question isn't about programming

Answer (score -1):

I think the use of a "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" or a "CORS" Chrome extension will solve your problem

Comment: Shrey, did my answer solved your problem ? I'm curious to know ;-)